# Service to consume pushed SOAP messages indefinitely?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, push

I'm in a situation where another system in my domain is sending SOAP messages periodically to a given number of IP:Port addresses, and i went to be able to receive those.
Now, I have experience with Web Services a bit, But this is different.

I thought that what i basically need is some kind of Listener service running and getting those SOAP messages. The service needs to be in .NET and probably written in C#.

I'm currently looking at anything from simple HttpListener implementation to WCF. How would you suggest to go about this?

Note: This is an existing interoperability interface, Which is why i'm not just doing a Web service or WCF Service and have the other system call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the contract is supposed to look like, you could create a simple WCF service that accepts it and listen on the specified IP:Port. WCF using BasicHttpBinding is expecting to receive a SOAP message, so with things set up correctly it should handle it.

If you don't, and can't figure it out for some reason (or it changes a lot), then you could just open a socket that accepts traffic on that port and parse the messages out yourself when they turn up.

Comment: Yeah, I have the XSD scheme for the SOAP message entirely. I'll research using WCF BasicHttpbinding, Thanks!

Comment: Tridus - When you said if i know what the contract looked like, Did you mean a .NET/WCF Interface contract? in my case, A linux client is sending me a SOAP message using gSoap. So while i know what the SOAP XML should be like, I don't have a contract per-se - and the sending side isn't executing an operation on my side.

Comment: The SOAP messsage will be enough to figure out what the contract should look like, as it contains the name of the method being called and the data being sent (and the reply expected, if any). You can create a WCF contract with a method that has a matching name and the right parameters, and it should be able to accept it.

Comment: I ended up using SVCUtil to generate some of that code and built the service based on that. Your answer(s) helped me understand a bit more what's going on though, thanks again!